# How to place the count variable in this gcd program based on Euclid's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, count, greatest-common-divisor

First of all, this is the Euclid's algorithm for calculating `GCD` (those who know it can skip straight away to the code).

`GCD(m,n)=GCD(n,m mod n)` and you keep performing this function until you get something like this: `GCD(m,n)=GCD(answer,0)`. When you get this, you stop, that's what my program is trying to do. However I want to find another thing as well. The number of recursive GCD calls/divisions(let's call this variable as COUNT for conversation purposes) it takes for it to actually ARRIVE at the answer. For example

`GCD(60,24) = GCD (24, 12) = GCD (12, 0) =12` so the COUNT here would be 3(including the last one) since we used Euclid's algorithm twice.

P.S in the code below, I am trying to print COUNT along with GCD values for a combination of numbers and I seem to get wrong answers.

P.P.S I hope I have explained this properly.

Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int gcd(int m , int n);
int count=0;
int main()
{
    int m,n;
    for(m=1;m<=10;m++)
    {
        for(n=1;n<=m;n++)
        {
            printf("gcd of %d, %d is :%d",m,n,gcd(m,n));
            printf(" with %d iterations\n",count);
        }
    }
}

int gcd(int m , int n)
{
    if(n==0)
    {
        return m;
        count=0;
    }
    if(m<n)
    {
        //swapping both a and b
        m=m+n;
        n=m-n;
        m=m-n;
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
        return gcd(n, m%n); 
    }
}
```

Comment: just a side-note, but a more elegant solution would be to use a reference to the counter as parameter - or alternatively an `int*`. This way you could avoid global variables.

Comment: Yeah din't think about it while starting the program, will keep that in mind from next time. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `count = 0` is after the `return` statement. Thus, it's never executed!

However, even after you switch `count = 0` and `return`, it's still incorrect because you basically set `count` to `0` after you increase `count`. For example:

```
gcd(60,24) => count++ => count = 1
gcd(24, 12) => count++ => count = 2
gcd(12, 0) => count = 0 => count = 0
```

The right way is to do the following:

```
count = 0
gcd(60,24) => count++ => count = 1
gcd(24, 12) => count++ => count = 2
gcd(12, 0) => count++ => count = 3
```

Also, the flow of your code is incorrect. What will happen if you call `gcd(5, 15)`? You swap `5` and `15`, but then you didn't return anything at all! The way to fix it is to remove the `else` statement.

Here's the refactored code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int gcd(int m , int n);
int gcd_wrapper(int m, int n);

int count=0;

int main(){
    int m,n;
    for(m=1;m<=10;m++)
    {
        for(n=1;n<=m;n++)
        {
            printf("gcd of %d, %d is :%d",m,n,gcd_wrapper(m,n));
            printf(" with %d iterations\n",count);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int gcd_wrapper(int m, int n) {
    count = 0;
    return gcd(m, n);
}

int gcd(int m , int n){
    count++;
    if(n == 0){
        return m;
    }
    if(m < n){
        //swapping both a and b
        m=m+n;
        n=m-n;
        m=m-n;
    }
    return gcd(n, m%n); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works perfectly, but why did you add another function gcd_wrapper? Is it not possible to include that count=0 statement in the gcd function?

Comment: Keep in mind that `gcd` is a recursive function, meaning it is called not only at `printf("gcd of %d, %d is :%d",m,n,gcd_wrapper(m,n));`. You also call it at `return gcd(n, m%n); `. If you set `count = 0` in `gcd`, `count` will be set to `0` in every iteration, thus resulting in incorrect value.

Comment: Oh wow, din't think about it that way. Thanks a lot for your help. :D

Comment: And also I learnt a new way of using a wrapper (literally a function around a function). Thanks.